# Additional fitting parameters for cross-validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

With `scikit-learn`, is there a way to pass additional parameters to the `fit` method of a classifier, when using `cross_val_score`? For instance, how would you specify the `sample_weight` or `class_prior`, for a `MultinomialNB` classifier:

[`scikit-learn`'s page about `MultinomialNB`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html)

Comment: This is not possible at the moment. Feel free to open a feature request on the issues page. You can use a cross-validation object and write the loop yourself as a workaround.

Comment: Andreas: this comment is the best current answer to the question: you should move it as an answer instead of a comment so that OP can validate it and so that it does not shows up as unanswered in the stackoverflow question lists.

Comment: @ogrisel is there a way to promote the comment to an answer? Or do I have to delete the comment and just resubmit it?

Comment: I don't have the rights to do that myself. Just copy and paste the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did as suggested, and implemented the feature myself, which has been added to the 0.13 release, as `fit_params`:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html

Comment: @MutluSimsek I have updated the link thanks.